# Prove that if a coin comes up tails, then it isn't two-headed

Tags: probability

I don't know, I saw this asked and I was wondering how it's even possible to prove this (or why it requires a proof).

Comment: As you say, why does this require a proof ?

Comment: And if you must, you can do a "proof" by contradiction. Suppose that both sides were heads, could the coin ever land a tails?

Answer (score 0):

Define a coin to be an object with two states which have a $0.5$ probability of occuring. Then say that the coin states can either be Heads or Tails. You have 4 possible states:

- Heads - Heads
- Heads - Tails
- Tails - Heads
- Tails - Tails

Clearly if after a toss the coin is tails then it eliminates the possible Heads - Heads option thus proven.